# What type of gravel should I use to top a sand driveway?

Tags: driveway

I live in Central Fl and we have a sugar sand driveway and when its dry like it is now our driveway turns into a never ending sand pit and getting in and out is difficult what would be the best type of gravel to put on top of this that is durable ?

Comment: i would add kitty litter to the sand under the base to add clay, which should firm it up some and result in better compaction.

Answer (score 1):

I would use crushed quarry or shale but not crushed river rock. Quarry and shale lock together quite well but crushed river rock moves around.

I would want at least 4” (we put 6” in our horse stalls) and compact it. With rubber mats over the top, it is good and solid even with our warlander (a draft / Andalusian cross 17-2 hands) a big horse.

Answer (score 0):

Evenly graded crushed rock is very good for compaction and is used under asphalt roadways.

However, if you install it on an unstable base (like your sand) it will not remain compacted, unless it’s restrained.

Sand has great bearing capacity as long as it is restrained. That is to say, if the sand is restrained, like in a recessed area, then it would make an acceptable base for crushed rock. However, if the sand has an exposed edge that can blow away, get pushed aside, etc., then it will weaken and become unstable.